# How can I loop through a nested dictionary when the key meets a condition?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary

```
{
   'Fruit': {
          'PriceNoted':0,
          'QuantityNoted':0},
   'Tools': {
       'PriceNoted':0,
       'QuantityNoted':0}
}
```

When I a list of texts that is only for Fruit I only want to the code to populate the values for Fruit and if the texts are for Tools then it should populate for Tools only. I've tried writing this code, but every time it keeps populating all the values for the nested dictionary:

```
    for z in GoodsUrl:
        r = requests.get(z)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

                
        for h,v in goodsdict.items():
            if type(v) is dict and h == k:
                for nk, nv in v.items():
                    results = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(nk)), recursive=True)
                    if len(results)> 0:
                        v[nk] += 1
                        GoodslistResult.append(k)
                        scount += 1
                        if scount == len(attributelist):
                            break   
                    if scount == len(attributelist):
                        break
                if scount == len(attributelist):
                    break
            if scount == len(attributelist) or k != h:
                    break
```

Can anyone tell me how I can populate specific values if the key meets a condition?

Comment: Instead of ```if type(v) is dict``` you could just do ```if isinstance(v, dict)```

Comment: Also, is ```Tools``` supposed to be string?

Comment: Thanks @ewong Tools would be in another list of strings. So it generates a list for Fruit then searches those strings after that it generates a new list for Tools Price and Quantity noted there.